# Convergence of $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}dx$

Tags: calculus

> For what values of $p,q\in\mathbb{R}$ the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}dx$ converges?

I tried to use the comparison limit theorem with $\int_{1}^{\infty}x^pdx$. We then have the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}\cdot\frac{1}{x^p}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^q}$$

which is $\neq 0$ if and only if $q\le 0$. Then if $q\le 0$, the integral converges if and only if $\int_{1}^{\infty}x^pdx$ converges if and only if $p<-1$.

Does anyone know what can we do in the case $q>0$?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't compare with $x^\alpha$ instead of $x^p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Assume $q>0$, then, as $ x \to \infty$, you just have
$$
\frac{x^p}{1+x^q} \sim \frac1{x^{(q-p)}}.
$$ then you may conclude by comparison.

Comment: Oh, this is perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For example, and since $\;x\ge1\;$ :

$$\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}\le x^{p-q}\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\;p-q<-1\implies\;\text{the integral converges}$$

Answer (score 2):

We know that $\frac{x^p}{1 + x^q} \leq \frac{x^p}{x^q}   = x^{p - q}$

This means
\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty \frac{x^p}{1 + x^q} dx \leq \int_1^\infty x^{p-q}dx
\end{equation}
If the integral on the right converges then so does the one on the left, as it is strictly less than or equal to the right. The left integral only converges when $p - q < -1$ .